# revealing the deep structure of "as few as"

Tags: conjunctions

The meeting was attended by as few as 6 people.

In this case, is there any comparison or contrast? if so, would you please reveal it?

Thanks

Comment: Replace it by "only six people" or by "no more than six  people". As to me, I don't see a comparison here. For me it is just an idiomatic formula.

Answer (score 2):

There is no comparison or contrast here, since you have nothing to compare *people* to. The words *as few as* simply the stresses the fact that there are *not many*, *only a small amount* of people, more specifically: 6 people.

You could rephrase the sentence like so:

> - The meeting was attended by **just** 6 people.
> - The meeting was attended by **only** 6 people.
> - The meeting was attended by **no more than** 6 people.

So, *as few as* is used to focus on the amount of people, stressing that there are only a few while more would have been expected under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

That structure is used to focus the reader on how relatively small the lower number of a range is, 6 in this case.

For example:

> Your seminar was a waste of time, it was attended by as few as 6 people.

Meaning, you had 6-10 attend but a good seminar would have been attended by 30, 40, 100 people.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "deep structure" but I will answer the best I can.

When you say "as few as" you are comparing the number, in this case 6, to "few". As an additional example, when you say "as many as" you comparing the number to how great the number is.

> The event was really empty. As few as 20 people showed.

As opposed to:

> My birthday party was amazing! As many as 60 people came to dinner!

Comment: I am confused as I am wondering if there is any comparison or not?

Comment: I see a comparison between few and the number.

Comment: Of course, this structure derives from a comparison formula: "as few people as six people are few".  But today it has the sense of "only", and no one thinks about a comparison any more, and I doubt that everyone will manage to reconstruct the original formula of comparision as such a comparison simply is clumsy.